# Apply diff image on the original image c#

Tags: c#, image-comparison

suppose i have two image with same height and width. pic1.jpg & pic2.jpg. two image look pretty same with minimum difference. with the help of below routine we can get the difference between two images.this below routine is not my routine.

```
public class ImageDifferences
{
    private static ILog mLog = LogManager.GetLogger("ImageDifferences");

    public static unsafe Bitmap PixelDiff(Image a, Image b)
    {
        if (!a.Size.Equals(b.Size)) return null;
        if (!(a is Bitmap) || !(b is Bitmap)) return null;

        return PixelDiff(a as Bitmap, b as Bitmap);
    }

    public static unsafe Bitmap PixelDiff(Bitmap a, Bitmap b)
    {
        Bitmap output = new Bitmap(
            Math.Max(a.Width, b.Width),
            Math.Max(a.Height, b.Height),
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Rectangle recta = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, a.Size);
        Rectangle rectb = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, b.Size);
        Rectangle rectOutput = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, output.Size);

        BitmapData aData = a.LockBits(recta, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        BitmapData bData = b.LockBits(rectb, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        BitmapData outputData = output.LockBits(rectOutput, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        try
        {
            byte* aPtr = (byte*)aData.Scan0;
            byte* bPtr = (byte*)bData.Scan0;
            byte* outputPtr = (byte*)outputData.Scan0;
            int len = aData.Stride * aData.Height;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                // For alpha use the average of both images (otherwise pixels with the same alpha won't be visible)
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                    *outputPtr = (byte)((*aPtr + *bPtr) / 2);
                else
                    *outputPtr = (byte)~(*aPtr ^ *bPtr);

                outputPtr++;
                aPtr++;
                bPtr++;
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            a.UnlockBits(aData);
            b.UnlockBits(bData);
            output.UnlockBits(outputData);
        }
    }
}
}
```

after getting the difference how could i merge the difference on first image.

this below way we can merge

```
using (Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    grfx.DrawImage(newImage, x, y)
}
```

but we need to know the x & y from where the new image will be drawn on first image. can any one tell me how can i get the x & y position from the above routine called **PixelDiff()** thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The routine uses the coordinates 0,0 for both input images, and the same for the difference image, so you would use the same to draw the difference image.

Comment: i do not know whether you understand my question or not. basically i want to draw difference image on the first image.DrawImage() need x & y coordinate. if i can provide right x & y coordinate then i can draw the difference on first image at right location which causes to generate a image which would look same as 2nd image. i hope i am clear.

Comment: suppose you have tow images or screen shot of your desktop with minimum difference. u can programmatically extract the difference between two images and later u can merge the difference on first image which generate a another image which would look like second screen shot of your desktop. i just need to know how could i get the right x & y when i extract the difference between two images. if i know right x & y then i can dump the diff image on the first image with right x & y that generate 3rd image which would look like same as 2nd image.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. The routine is reading from both images starting at coordinates 0,0 (`Point.Empty`), and writing the result into the diff image at 0,0. Therefore if you draw the 0,0 coordinate of the diff image at 0,0 on the first image, they will match.